# Android-How to get the content of the inner tag of xml in android

Tags: android, xml-parsing, feed, domparser

I have got a xml from an url which contain the following tags,
 
http://www.ZZZZZZZZZZZZz.jpg' width='90' height='62'>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

I need to get the link inside the img src='http://www.ZZZZZZZZZZZZz.jpg' and the content inside the description say AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA seprately in astring how can i achieve it.

i have written a code but it doesnt take the url of the image

```
private void ProcessXml(Document data) {
    if (data!=null){
       feedList=new ArrayList<>();
        Element root=data.getDocumentElement();
        Node channel=root.getChildNodes().item(1);
        NodeList items=channel.getChildNodes();
        for (int i=0;i<items.getLength();i++){
            Node currentChild=items.item(i);
            if (currentChild.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")){
                GetterSetter getterSetter=new GetterSetter();
                NodeList itemchild=currentChild.getChildNodes();
                for (int j=0;j<itemchild.getLength();j++){
                    Node current=itemchild.item(j);
                    Log.d("aaa", "ProcessXml: ="+current.getTextContent());
                    if (current.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("title")){
                        getterSetter.setTitle(current.getTextContent());
                    }
                    else            if(current.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("description")){
                             getterSetter.setDescription(current.getTextContent());
                    }
                    else if (current.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("link")){
                        getterSetter.setLink(current.getTextContent());
                    }
                    else if (current.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("pubDate")){
                        getterSetter.setPubDate(current.getTextContent());
                    }else if (current.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("enclosure url")){
                        String url=current.getAttributes().item(0).getTextContent();
                        getterSetter.setThumbnail(url);
                    }

                   }
                feedList.add(getterSetter);
                Log.d("qqq", "thumbnail: ="+getterSetter.getThumbnail());


            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Jsoup](https://jsoup.org) library may help.

in your build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.9.1'
    ...
}
```

Parse like this:

```
String html = "<img src='http://www.ZZZZZZZZZZZZz.jpg' width='90' height='62'>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
String imgUrl = doc.select("img").attr("src"); //http://www.ZZZZZZZZZZZZz.jpg
String description = doc.text(); //AAAAAAAAAAAA...
```

Comment: thank you, but doc.select and doc.text is not working

Comment: oops.. If you can post your code using jsoup, please add to your answer.